# MATE disable both mouse clicks to act as middle mouse

Tags: fedora, mouse, mate-desktop

I am on Fedora 24 with the MATE desktop environment. I did a `dnf update` and I have noticed now that when I simultaneously press both mouse buttons it acts as if I have clicked middle mouse down.

Is there any way to disable this? I have never noticed this before so I think it may be related to the upgrade I just did. MATE 1.16.1 is running at the moment. Could not find anything when googling/looking through dconf/other settings.

Answer (score 4):

On MATE you can set the mouse settings property **middle-button-enabled** to **false** to disable the emulation.<sup>[1](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1473259#p1473259)</sup> It doesn't disable the middle click altogether.

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse middle-button-enabled false
```

Version 1.21 of mate-control-center adds a checkbox for this in the mouse settings.<sup>[2](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/pull/347)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/100250/how-do-i-disable-both-button-click-acting-as-middle-click-in-mate/?answer=100309#post-id-100309:

```
You can disable left+right click acting as middle click for all devices system-wide by adding the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-3rdbutton.conf with the following content:

Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "middle button"
   MatchIsPointer "on"
   MatchDriver "libinput"
   Option "MiddleEmulation" "off"
EndSection

Adapted from the following Stack Exchange answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284782
```